# Sort letters by ASCII and number of their occurrences in a file

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, ascii

I made a function that counts how many times a letter occurs in a file. I cannot figure out how to sort it by frequency, and if two letters occur the same number of times, the letter which is "bigger" by ASCII occurs before the other one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void process_input_file(const char* input_file, const char* output_file) {
    FILE* input = fopen(input_file, "r");
    if (input == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening the input file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int occurrences[26] = {0};
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            c = toupper(c);
            occurrences[c - 'A']++;
        }
    }
    fclose(input);

    FILE* output = fopen(output_file, "w");
    if (output == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening the output file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (occurrences[i] > 0) {
            fprintf(output, "%c", i + 'A');
        }
    }
    fclose(output);
}

int main() {
    char input_file[1000];
    printf("Enter the name of the input file: ");
    scanf("%s", input_file);
    process_input_file(input_file, "statistics.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

One example would be a file that has this written in it:

```
"Ovo je primjer znakovne datoteke"
```

It should write in another file:

```
EOAJKNRTVDIMPZ
```

But it does this:

```
ADEIJKMNOPRTVZ
```

I tried changing so I compare it from the back of the array because then they are the biggest letters by ASCII but it didn't work

```
for (int i = 26; i > 0; count--) {
    for (int j = 26 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (occurrences[j] == i) {
            fprintf(output, "%c", j + 'A');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are doing any sorting. See: [`qsort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). But you will need more than the array you have to store the letter and its count.

Comment: it didn't work but i can add it below the code and the outputs

Comment: You could use an array of say `struct rec { int letter; int frequency; }` then you can sort the array. Sort by frequency, unless they are the same, when you sort by letter.

Comment: it is updated now .

Comment: `occurrences[c - 'A']` is a problem in _locales_ that have more than 26 letters.

Comment: @001 your advice helped me i fixed it now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage `qsort` to solve this by writing a comparator function which compares structs containing both a character, and a count of those characters. An array of these structs, one for each letter in the alphabet, functions as a lookup table.

A single pass through the input string tallies characters into this array. We can then use the custom comparator and `qsort` to order them accordingly.

Finally, we loop over the structs and for any with a count greater than zero (characters that actually occur in the input string) we write them in order into a dynamically allocated char array. This is dynamically allocated so that its lifetime survives the `sorted` function.

By breaking down problems into smaller problems, each function is smaller and easier to understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct char_info {
    char ch;
    size_t count;
};

int cmp_char_info(const void *a, const void *b) {
    struct char_info c = *(struct char_info *)a;
    struct char_info d = *(struct char_info *)b;

    if (c.count < d.count) return 1;
    if (c.count > d.count) return -1;
    if (c.ch < d.ch) return -1;
    if (c.ch > d.ch) return 1;

    return 0;
}

char *sorted(const char *input_str) {
    const char *alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    struct char_info info[26];

    for (size_t i = 0; alphabet[i]; i++) {
        info[i] = (struct char_info){ alphabet[i], 0 };
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; input_str[i]; i++) {
        char ch = input_str[i];
        if (!isalpha(ch)) continue;
        ch = toupper(ch);
        info[ch - 'A'].count++;
    }

    qsort(info, 26, sizeof(struct char_info), cmp_char_info);

    char *result = calloc(27, 1);
    size_t j = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (info[i].count > 0) {
            result[j++] = info[i].ch;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    char *output = sorted("Ovo je primjer znakovne datoteke");

    printf("%s\n", output);

    free(output);
}
```

Output:

```
EOAJKNRTVDIMPZ
```

Comment: The comparator function is neater if you sequence it `if (c.count < d.count) return -1; else if (c.count > d.count) return +1; else if (c.ch < d.ch) return -1; else if (c.ch > d.ch) return +1; else return 0;`. You can also play games like: `if (c.count != d.count) return (c.count < d.count) - (c.count > d.count); return (c.ch < d.ch) - c.ch > d.ch);`. The `else` keywords in the first code are optional; the prior statement is always a return, so a simple `if` is adequate each time.  OTOH, I prefer the `else` there.

Comment: You're mostly not wrong. Since the OP needs the count in descending order, `if (c.count > d.count) return -1;`

Comment: Oh — I missed ascending vs descending and gave the ascending sort for the counts.  It's an important but easily fixed detail, as you show.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the final array, eliminating the values as you find the largest, so each next-found is the next-greatest count

```c
const char ALPHABET[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

/* results
     occurrences  array of counts of letters in alphabetical order
     length       length of occurrences (always 26)
   fills occurrences with -1s after run, 0s may be left too
*/
void results(int occurrences[], const int length) {
    int tmp = -1;
    int idx = -1;
    while(1) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)  // search for the largest value
            if (occurrences[i] > tmp) {
                idx = i;                   // save position of max value
                tmp = occurrences[idx];
            }
        if (tmp < 1) break;   // end while when all values are cleared
        tmp = ALPHABET[idx];  // just go ahead and re-use as a char
        printf("%c", tmp);
        occurrences[idx] = -1;  // flush member so next highest is found
        tmp = -1;               // reset tmp for the next loop
    }
    printf("\n");  // flush the buffer (alt: fill and write char[] + \n\0 );
}
```